# Base64 encoded file says "GZIP", but decoding it in Python outputs corrupt HTML

Tags: base64, gzip, recovery

I'm having trouble reading data from files I have from an old backup (Windows system).

Example how the content looks like:

```
GZIP
-}_HTML>

<H AD>

<META HTTP-EQUV="Conten-Type" CO!TENT="tex/html; chrset=wind&ws-1252">
```

It's almost proper HTML... but some characters are corrupted.

In Base64, it looks like this:

```
R1pJUAwAAAAKAAAALX0AAF9IVE1MPg0KPEggQUQ+DQo8TUVUQSBIVFRQLUVRVQ5WPSJDb250ZW4ZLVR5cGUiIENPIVRFTlQ9InRleBwvaHRtbDsgY2gTcnNldD13aW5kJndzLTEyNTIi
```

Since it says "GZIP" at the top, I tried decompressing it with gzip in  Python.

```
import zlib
import base64

s = "R1pJUAwAAAAKAAAALX0AAF9IVE1MPg0KPEggQUQ+DQo8TUVUQSBIVFRQLUVRVQ5WPSJDb250ZW4ZLVR5cGUiIENPIVRFTlQ9InRleBwvaHRtbDsgY2gTcnNldD13aW5kJndzLTEyNTIi"

s = base64.b64decode(s.encode('Latin1'))

zlib.decompress(s, 31)
```

Though I'm getting the error:

> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Same with this code:

```
import gzip

s = gzip.decompress(s)
s = str(s,'utf-8')

print(s)
```

> gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'GZ')

Any idea how I can recover data from this file?

Comment: Gzipped content does not look like original content. What kind of backup is this?

Comment: It's a database backup which is supposed to contain documents in HTML format. The data is stored in the database as this string, which I believe is Base64. When I base64-decode it, it looks like the first code example in my question (i.e. starting with "GZIP").

Comment: Have you extracted the string correctly from the database? How is it stored there, which field type and collation?

Comment: I only have the export files from the database. The XML looks like this: `FieldName="[CDATA[XXXX]]"`, where X always seems to be in multiples of 4. For example, starting like this:`Data="[CDATA[R1pJUAgAAAAKAAAAjS8AAFl`. So the string in my question is the XXXX part (enclosed in the inner square brackets).

Comment: Is the content stored as base64 in the database, or was the base64 introduced by the thing that created the XMLs? Are the database fields `binary` or `varchar`?

Comment: The base64 must have been generated by the export tool. I also have .txt exports, and those show the data in the same "corrupt" form that I get when I decode the base64 encoded version (`H AD> <META HTTP-EQUV="Conten-Type" CO!TENT="tex/html; chrset=wind&ws-1252">`). I think the field type was BLOB.

Comment: Then likely the pages were not written to the database in a correct encoding in the first place, so there is nothing to restore.

Answer (score 1):

It is neither gzip nor any sort of compression at all. Despite the word "GZIP" at the top. It is what you see.